# Post a Jira Comment and set the "viewable by" via Rest API

Tags: jira-rest-api

I am writing a small script which uses the Jira Rest API.

Aim:
Make a comment on a Jira ticket, which is viewable only by a certain group

Language: Python

Issue:
I cant find out what to set so only a certain group can view the new comment made via Jira Rest API

Any ideas would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Please read [ask] and then show us what you've tried and the specific problems/exceptions you're having.

Comment: @EngineerDollery, edited, hope its better now.

Comment: @EngineerDollery
Still been googling and got nothing, even the python rest client for jira doesnt seem to support this. Any ideas?

As for what I have tried, I cant find anything to try, I can successfully make a comment via Jira REST API, just not one with "viewable by" set.